# How to create csv with hashed entries in Node

Tags: node.js, hash

I'm trying to create a list of hashed email addresses in a csv file. I can hash a basic string, like this:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var name = 'johndoe@example.com';
var hash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(name).digest('hex');
console.log(hash);
```

But I am having trouble figuring out how to hash each individual item in a csv file.

When I use the following code, I get a `writeableStream is not defined` error.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readableStream = fs.createReadStream('routes/Workbook1.csv');
var writableStream = fs.createWriteStream('routes/Workbook2.csv');
var hash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(writeableStream).digest('hex');

readableStream.pipe(writableStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation of [hash.update](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_hash_update_data_input_encoding) it takes data as buffer or String, `WriteStream` object is not a correct fit for it.

So, the line below will always error out:

```
crypto.createHash('sha256').update(writeableStream).digest('hex')
```

You need to explicitly read CSV file and extract the email addresses from data and then hash them and then write it to an output CSV file.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still having trouble understanding how to hash each entry individually.